# Find all subsets of a vector that sum up to another vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics

I'm looking for a way to make my code more simple.  This code takes a list of vectors and returns all subset of that list that sum up to another vector.

For example:

> `{'a','b','c'}` is the subset consisting of: `a (1100000)`, `b (0110000)`, and `c (0011000)`.

```
def AddVectors(A, B):
    if not A:
        return B
    if not B:
        return A
    return [A[i] + B[i] for i in range(len(A))]

def SumVectorList(lst, SuperSet):
    result = []
    for l in lst:
        if not result:
            result = SuperSet[l]
        else:
            for j in range(len(l)):
                result = AddVectors(result, SuperSet[l[j]])
    return result

def GetPowerSet(lst):
    result = [[]]
    for x in lst:
        result.extend([subset + [x] for subset in result])
    return result

S = {'a': [one, one, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'b': [0, one, one, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     'c': [0, 0, one, one, 0, 0, 0], 'd': [0, 0, 0, one, one, 0, 0],
     'e': [0, 0, 0, 0, one, one, 0], 'f': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, one, one]}
P = GetPowerSet(S)
u = [0, 0, one, 0, 0, one, 0]
v = [0, one, 0, 0, 0, one, 0]
u_0010010 = {y for x in P for y in x if SumVectorList(x, S) == u}
u_0100010 = {y for x in P for y in x if SumVectorList(x, S) == v}
```

Comment: What does your code do ? What is it supposed to do ? Does it work ? I've tried replacing `one` by `1` and it is now running fine but it doesn't seem to be doing much.

Comment: one should not be replace with 1. The one in this case is 1 in GF2. So one+one=0 where as 1+1 in R = 2

Comment: @Josay As stated about I'm trying to find subset of S that when summed over GF2 you get the value of u or v respectively. I left out the GF2 portion, sorry. The code works just fine. I just was wondering how I could make it cleaner and with less lines maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes sense now. Can you give the definition of `one` (and any other things we might need for testing purposes) ?

Comment: @Josay you can go to http://resources.codingthematrix.com and Download GF2.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) giving the Style Guide for Python Code.

Now, in `AddVectors` (or `add_vectors`), it seems like you assume that A and B have the same size. You could achieve the same result with `zip`.

```
def add_vectors(a, b):
    assert(len(a)==len(b))
    return [sum(i) for i in zip(a,b)]
```

I have to go, I'll some more later :-)